# Change the name of the node using xsl:copy-of

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using XSLT to denormalized an XML document.

The problem is that the same name of the node is used in different levels, and this results in duplicates in the result file.

e.g.

The XML source file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Customers>
    <Customer>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Name>John Madsen</Name>
        <Accounts>
            <Account>
                <ID>111</ID>
                <Name>AAA</Name>
                <Value>11234</Value>                
            </Account>
            <Account>
                <ID>222</ID>
                <Name>BBB</Name>
                <Value>64</Value>
            </Account>
        </Accounts>        
    </Customer>

    <Customer>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <Name>Dona M. Graduate</Name>
        <Accounts>
            <Account>
                <ID>333</ID>
                <Name>CCC</Name>
                <Value>5215</Value>                
            </Account>
            <Account>
                <ID>555</ID>
                <Name>FFF</Name>
                <Value>6325</Value>
            </Account>
        </Accounts>        
    </Customer>
</Customers>
```

I want to transform it a flat list of Accounts, repeating the information regarding the Customers, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Accounts>
    <Account>
        <CustomerID>1</CustomerID>
        <CustomerName>John Madsen</CustomerName>
        <ID>111</ID>
        <Name>AAA</Name>
        <Value>11234</Value>                
    </Account>
    <Account>
        <CustomerID>1</CustomerID>
        <CustomerName>John Madsen</CustomerName>
        <ID>222</ID>
        <Name>BBB</Name>
        <Value>64</Value>
    </Account>
    <Account>
        <CustomerID>2</CustomerID>
        <CustomerName>Dona M. Graduate</CustomerName>
        <ID>333</ID>
        <Name>CCC</Name>
        <Value>5215</Value>                
    </Account>
    <Account>
        <CustomerID>2</CustomerID>
        <CustomerName>Dona M. Graduate</CustomerName>
        <ID>555</ID>
        <Name>FFF</Name>
        <Value>6325</Value>
    </Account>
</Accounts>
```

I am using the following XLS code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Accounts>
        <xsl:for-each select="Customers/Customer/Accounts/Account">
            <Account>
                <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::Customer/*[not(*)] "/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
            </Account>                                
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Accounts>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And I am getting this result, note how the Account has two ID nodes and to Name nodes, one if the Account ID and Name and the other is the Customer ID and Name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Accounts>
   <Account>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Name>John Madsen</Name>
      <ID>111</ID>
      <Name>AAA</Name>
      <Value>11234</Value>
   </Account>
   <Account>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Name>John Madsen</Name>
      <ID>222</ID>
      <Name>BBB</Name>
      <Value>64</Value>
   </Account>
   <Account>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Name>Dona M. Graduate</Name>
      <ID>333</ID>
      <Name>CCC</Name>
      <Value>5215</Value>
   </Account>
   <Account>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Name>Dona M. Graduate</Name>
      <ID>555</ID>
      <Name>FFF</Name>
      <Value>6325</Value>
   </Account>
</Accounts>
```

How can I add a prefix to the copied ID and Name from the Customer node?

Regards
Rafi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **copy-of** instruction copies the selected nodeset and you cannot modify it, therefore i recommend using **apply-templates** instead and perform operation in a separate template. The following code will do the job for you:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Accounts>
        <xsl:for-each select="Customers/Customer/Accounts/Account">
            <Account>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::Customer/*[not(*)]"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
            </Account>                                
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Accounts>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Customer/*[not(*)]">
    <xsl:element name="{concat('Customer', name())}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, the answer is exactly what I was trying to achive.